# Multilpe python versions and interpreters

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, python-3.3, pycharm

I am trying to setup python 2.7.6 on my windows 7 machine (python 3.3.3 was installed first). When selecting the project interpreter after adding it in settings-project interpreter, I get this error

> File "C:\Python33\Lib\site.py", line 173 file=sys.stderr) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When initially adding the python 2.7 interpreter in the settings page (as compared to adding the virtual environment above), it gives this error message

> Cannot setup python SDK at C: .... . The SDK seems invalid.

I also get a similar error when adding any virtual env based on that interpreter.

I've added the python27 paths in the Paths box as in the picture, but it seems to be looking at the path set in windows. If I have to change that, doesnt that defeat the point of being able to select multiple interpreters?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: PyCharm's project interpreters]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a really silly mistake: I was messing with `PYTHONPATH` instead of `PATH`. I added both `PYTHON33` and `PYTHON27` to my `PATH` and it worked.

Comment: I deleted the `PYTHONPATH` variable and my life quit being hell. As much.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these commands before you run your UI

```
set PYTHONHOME=C:\Python33
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python33\lib
```

Comment: I had the opposite problem -- I needed to remove [PYTHONHOME](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME) (which was pointed at Python 3) so that it wouldn't override the Python 2 interpreter's library location.