# Python 3 does not run, I edited the system variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to run python 3 I get this error:

```
C:\Users\owner>python
File "C:\Python33\lib\site.py", line 173
file=sys.stderr)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have never edited the site.py file.

I was running python 2 before, but I want to use python 3 so I edited the System Variables:

```
 C:\Users\owner\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Python33;C:\Python33\Scripts;
```

when I edit them back to use python 2 it works fine:

```
C:\Users\owner\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23399867/2877364

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to changing `PATH`, also change `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME`.  See, e.g., [this](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/foundationsqa/tickets/5-syntax-error-in-site-py?comment=296674713#comment:296674713).  For example:

```
set PYTHONHOME=C:\Python33
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python33\lib
```

(thanks to [aflat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630924/aflat), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23400374/2877364)).

**Edit**:

1. Confirm that you are setting the PATH so that it will take effect.  See Step 2 of [this](http://www.aaronstannard.com/how-to-setup-a-proper-python-environment-on-windows/).
2. At the command prompt, run `path` and confirm it lists `Python33` and not `Python27`.

Comment: Run `python --version` when you have the path set for Python 3.  What is the output?

Comment: It says it is using python 2.7